# Null Pointer Exception JsonArray Size

Tags: java, android, json

While retrieving objects from a Json file for an Android App, I am getting a NullPointerException when I try to access to the size of a Json Array.
Here is one Json Object of the "results" array:

```
results: [
{
aliases: null,
api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-26559/",
date_added: "2009-05-22 10:03:31",
date_last_updated: "2014-01-14 08:27:36",
deck: "All three Metroid Prime titles in one package. Metroid Prime and Metroid Prime 2:         Echoes are reworked to include 480p widescreen, motion controls, and achievements.",
description: "<h2>Overview</h2><p style="">Metroid Prime Trilogy is a single-disc compilation for the <a data-ref-id="3045-36" href="/wii/3045-36/" slug="wii">Nintendo Wii</a> consisting of <a data-ref-id="3030-15473" href="/metroid-prime/3030-15473/" slug="metroid-prime">Metroid Prime</a>, <a data-ref-id="3030-1597" href="/metroid-prime-2-echoes/3030-1597/" slug="metroid-prime-2-echoes">Metroid Prime 2: Echoes</a>, and <a data-ref-id="3030-4725" href="/metroid-prime-3-corruption/3030-4725/" slug="metroid-prime-3-corruption">Metroid Prime 3: Corruption</a>. The first two games in the series, originally released for the <a data-ref-id="3045-23" href="/gamecube/3045-23/" slug="gamecube">Nintendo GameCube</a>, have been updated with 480p widescreen support, improved graphic effects, and motion controls similar to those found in Metroid Prime 3.",
expected_release_day: null,
expected_release_month: null,
expected_release_quarter: null,
expected_release_year: null,
id: 26559,
image: {},
name: "Metroid Prime Trilogy",
number_of_user_reviews: 3,
original_game_rating: [],
original_release_date: "2009-08-24 00:00:00",
platforms: [
{
api_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-36/",
id: 36,
name: "Wii",
site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/wii/3045-36/",
abbreviation: "WII"
}
],
site_detail_url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/metroid-prime-trilogy/3030-26559/",
resource_type: "game"
}
```

I'm trying to get the size of "platforms", just because a game can be played, for example, both on PC and MAC:

```
if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
    Log.d(com.example.ludos2_0.MainActivity.TAG, "Response: "
            + response);
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(response);

    JsonArray items = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("results");

    String id = null;
    String title = null;
    String thumbnail = null;
    String description = null;
    String image = null;
    String platform = null;
    //ArrayList<String> platform = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {

        JsonObject itemObj = (JsonObject) items.get(index);
        id = itemObj.get("id").getAsString();
        title = itemObj.get("name").getAsString();
        thumbnail = ((JsonObject)itemObj.get("image")).
                get("tiny_url").getAsString();
        image = ((JsonObject)itemObj.get("image")).
                get("small_url").getAsString();
        description = itemObj.get("deck").getAsString();

        JsonArray platforms = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("platforms");           

        Log.d(com.example.ludos2_0.MainActivity.TAG,
                title);
        for (int j = 0; j < platforms.size(); j++) {
            JsonObject platformObj = (JsonObject) platforms.get(j);
            platform = platformObj.get("name").getAsString();
            videogamesList.add(new Videogame(id, title,
                    thumbnail, image, description, platform));
            Log.d(com.example.ludos2_0.MainActivity.TAG,
                    title + " " + platform);

        }

    }
```

But I get a NullPointerException at the line of the 'platforms.size()'.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my English, I'm italian!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `platforms.length()`?

Comment: `itemObj.getAsJsonArray("platforms")` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting values here

```
JsonArray platforms = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("platforms");
```

`platforms` is `null`, thats why you are gettin that exception

**Update:** 
 I have realized you have a problem here:

```
JsonArray platforms = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("platforms");
```

change to:

```
JsonArray platforms = itemObj.getAsJsonArray("platforms");
```

Comment: No idea why this was down voted but I see no reason for it. Voted back up.

Comment: because she copied my answer. you can see the answer was edited after I answered.

Comment: Thanks, I now realize that was so stupid ahahah! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting an object within platforms handler. Try this :

```
JsonArray platforms = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("platforms");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should get platforms from results not from your main object

```
JsonArray platforms = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("platforms");  //WRONG

JsonArray platforms = itemObj.getAsJsonArray("platforms"); //GOOD
```